# How to call a defined method inside another definition

Tags: ruby

```
@songs = [{artist: 'Artist', title: 'Title String', playback: '04:30'} etc]

def convert_to_secs
    a = str.split(':').map!{|x| x.to_i}
    return (a[0] * 60) + a[1]
end

def longest_possible(playback)
    @songs.select do |hsh|
        x = hsh[:playback].convert_to_secs
    end
    return x
end
```

When trying to call convert_to_seconds inside longest_possible I get the following error:

```
longest_possible.rb:5:in `block in longest_possible': private method 
`convert_to_secs' called for "04:30":String (NoMethodError)
from longest_possible.rb:4:in `select'
from longest_possible.rb:4:in `longest_possible'
from longest_possible.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

I'm not sure if my problem can be solved with scope operators, or whether this requires something with classes (not something I have touched upon yet.) Could you please point me in the right direction?

PS, ignore the functionality of the second function, i've not gotten around to making that one yet, just posted for example.

Comment: Try changing your method to `def convert_to_secs(a)` and the call to `x = convert_to_secs(hsh[:playback])`.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem seems to be that you call the method using the string as the receiver. It then tries to find the method `convert_to_secs` among the methods predefined for strings and doesn't find it. Instead, you should pass hsh[:playback] as an argument. So your code should look like this:

```
def convert_to_secs(str)  # Note the argument str introduced here
  # You don't need map! here. Normal map suffices.
  a = str.split(':').map {|x| x.to_i}
  # In Ruby, you can leave away the return keyword at the end of methods.
  (a[0] * 60) + a[1]
end

def longest_possible(playback)
  @songs.select do |hsh|
    x = convert_to_secs(hsh[:playback])
  end
  return x
end
```